# Firefox not displaying thumbnails for YouTube and eBay

Tags: firefox, youtube, thumbnails

I had a problem with the latest version of Firefox (74.0) and so downgraded to version 73.0.  Now Firefox won't display thumbnails for YouTube and eBay.  I have cleared the cache and cleared cookies for these sites, but the problem still persists.  I started Firefox in safe mode, but it did not help.  Here's what my subscriptions page looks like for YouTube:

[image]

Any ideas on how to go about debugging this problem?

I am on Windows 10 x64.

Comment: Have you checked with the network inspector (with images selected only)?

Comment: @Phoenix First off, thank you.  I just did what you suggested.  Most images indicate as "cached" under the Transferred column.  So I think the problem is that FF thinks the images are cached, but they're not, because of something (?) that went wrong during the downgrade that I did.  But as I said, I cleared cache and cookies. :(

Comment: Consider disabling cache with network inspector.

Comment: Even after reloading the page? That should ignore the cache. And, do you have a backup of your profile folder before FF 74?

Comment: @user3169 Yes, I have the old profile folder, but that's how it all started.  During the downgrade, it **forced** me to create a new profile.  It would not allow reuse of the old profile.  Afterwards, I followed directions from a site to copy old profile data into the new profile while FF was inactive.  That's how it got out of sync, I believe.

Comment: @Phoenix I disabled cache and network inspector started showing actual network transfers taking place for the images, but still the same result.  I think the transferred data is going to another folder that FF does not know about (old profile folder?).

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/recovering-important-data-from-an-old-profile#w_copying-files-between-profile-folders It would have told you what you can't copy. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/recover-user-data-missing-after-firefox-update This one involves switching profiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may solve your problem, if it is related to which profile is being used.
**To recover data from an old profile**
This one will involve switching profiles, the catch is that you can't delete any profiles.

1. Type in `about:profiles`. You should see something like this:[image]
2. It will list at least 1 profile, along with other profile
3. Find the profile you want to switch to and click `Set as Default Profile`.
4. You may need to restart Firefox.